# Does LLVM support IEEE-694?

Tags: assembly, llvm

Does LLVM generate [IEEE-694](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/694-1985.html) assembler bytecode or do I have to modify the source code for it?

Comment: What is "IEEE 649" ? IEEE 649-2006 standard is definitely unrelated here (IEEE Standard for Qualifying Class 1E Motor Control Centers for Nuclear Power Generating Stations)

Comment: It stands for IEEE std 694-1985, a standard for Microprocessor Assembly Language.

Comment: @user1038382 in the link you posted it prominently says "Status: Withdrawn Standard"

Answer (score 1):

If the ISA of your platform has assembler which is compatible with the aforementioned standard, then LLVM will generate such compatible output. Note that the standard was withdrawn , most probably because it's pretty useless - it cannot change the wide variety of the existing archs / assemblers.